# How do I calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{(2\pi x)}^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I just started studying limits a week ago and today I got this question on my YouTube feed. I am having a hard time with it.

The question is:

> Find the value of: $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{x!}{x^x})^\frac{1}{x}$

The answer to this question is $\frac{1}{e}$

There in the comment section, someone suggested to use the Stirling's approximation.  It states

> $n! \approx   e^{-n}*n^n*\sqrt{2\pi n}$

After putting this in the question it reduces down to:  proving that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{(2\pi x)}^\frac{1}{x}=1$

I just don’t know how to eliminate that $\pi$ in the expression. Wolfram Alpha suggested to use Puiseux series. Apparently, the wiki page is just too advanced for me to comprehend.

I would be really thankful to anyone who could shed some light on this problem!

( The video link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89d5f8WUf1Y&t=0s )

Comment: Hi @Aaryan. You should consider replacing the variable in the limit to be $n$ because we really are considering the factorial here which is a discrete function and is defined continuously only in terms of the Gamma function which has no role to play here. What's up though?

Comment: @ParasKhosla Haha Hi bro. Great to see you in SE. Liked Aakash?

Comment: Ya it's great. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why on earth would you need to eliminate $\pi$? This is actually a relatively simple limit. The easiest way I see to do this is to rewrite it as 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (2\pi x)^{\frac 1{2x}}$$
We can then compute
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log \left((2\pi x)^{\frac 1{2x}}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2x}\log 2\pi x$$
If you truly want, you can split this as 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2x}(\log 2\pi+\log x)$$
The limit is $0$, hence the original limit is $1$. Plugging it into the approximation gives you $e^{-1}$.

Comment: In order to avoid ambiguous, I believe using $\log\left((2\pi x)^{\frac1{2x}}\right)$ is better

Comment: @Kemono Sure, probably. Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: Holy Moly! I forgot that $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{\log(x)}{x})=0$ ! . Thank You so much :)

Comment: @Aaryan You're welcome.